# Using a dictionary that takes a list, a, as an argument and returns a list containing the elements of a that occur exactly once

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary, element

I've been stuck on this for a while (Python 2.x)

By using a `dict`, write a method `only_once(a)` that takes a list, `a`, as an argument and returns a list containing the elements of `a` that occur exactly once.  The elements must appear in the same order as their first occurrence in `a`.

```
def once (a):

    list=[]
    d = {}
    run=0

    for i in a: 
        d[i] = d.has_key(i)    

    print ([k for k in d.keys() if not d[k]]))
```

This prints the elements that only occur once but not in the order in which it was received

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key problem is that you iterate over the dictionary keys (the explicit `.keys()` is unnecessary, as you iterate over a dictionary's keys by default) to get the output; dictionaries are *unordered*. Instead, you need to use the input order:

```
def only_once(a):
    d = {}
    for item in a:
        if item not in d:
            d[item] = 0
        d[item] += 1
    return [item for item in a if d[item] == 1]
```

Note that your code never uses `list` (which, as it shadows a built-in, is a name you shouldn't use for your own variables) and `run`, so they should have been removed.

Comment: There are two elements 14 in the input, therefore the output should not include 14.  -14 is it's own number i know and it is OK that that is there because it only occurred once.  eg. input--> [14,14,-14]... the output should be [-14] because it only occurred once

Comment: Oh, I see. Your explanation was somewhat unclear. I have edited my answer; the central criticism, that you iterate over the keys, stands.

Comment: Ahh beautiful!  Yah sorry for being unclear.  Appreciate the help this is exactly what i was struggling to comprehend! Thanks :)

Comment: See also [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects), a dictionary subclass that does the work for you.